# React is not rendering in webpage? (w/Handlebars)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to implement react into a small piece of a website, but for some reason it is not rendering what so ever. I am using node, express, React, and handlebars.

landing.handlebars:

```
  <section class="section section-dark">
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/jsx" src="index.js"></script>
```

index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
  this.state = {
  name: null,
  email: null,
  message: null,
};
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

}
handleChange(event) {
const target = event.target;
const value = target.value;
const name = target.name;
this.setState({
  [name]: value
});
}
 handleSubmit(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 }
render() {
 return (
 <div className="App">
<h2 className="bottom">Send Message!</h2>
    <form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  className="bottom">
        <div className="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email"  onChange= {this.handleChange} value = {this.state.email} className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" />
            <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>

        <div classNameName="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Name:</label>
            <input type="text"  onChange= {this.handleChange}  value={this.state.name} className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>


        <div className="form-group">
            <label for="exampleTextarea">Message:</label>
            <textarea  onChange= {this.handleChange} value={this.state.message} className="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" value="submit" className="btn btn-primary"> <i 
  className="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
   );
   }
  }
 export default App;
```

It shows no sort of jsx file in the network tag at all besides the ones that are necessary (Jquery, bootstrap, etc)

Comment: Are you using Babel to transpile?

Comment: @AndrewLi I added babel as a dependency(npm install babel --save)? Sorry new to react.